# Wait for completion of threadpool tasks using Phaser

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, phaser

I want to return from my `executeTasks()` method only after all the tasks submitted to the threadpool are finished. Please note that my thread pool has configurable threadpoolsize and uses `SynchronousQueue` as the backing queue, so my for loop proceeds safely by submitting a task only if a thread is available. So, I just want to wait for the final tasks. I am using `Phaser` for this.

I've created a Phaser with 1 registered party i.e., the current thread and I register a new party to the Phaser before submitting a task to the threadpool, when the task finishes I deregister the task party. When for loop finishes by submitting the final tasks, I am hoping that my `arriveAndAwaitAdvance()` will wait for registered parties to arrive but it will only discover that all those parties are deregistered after some time and then move forward and return from my method.

I think that this will solve my problem. Please let me know if I am wrong or if there is any other better way to do this. Countdownlatch is not going to help as my threadpoolsize is configurable. I know that having a counter and monitor will solve this problem but I want out-of-the-box solution like Phaser.

```
private void executeTasks(TheadPoolExecutor threadPool, Iterator<String> it) {
    final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);

    for (final String id : IteratorUtils.iterable(it)) {
        phaser.register();
        threadPool.execute(() -> {
        // phaser.arrive();
            try {
                thread.sleep(10000 * id.length());
            } finally {
                phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
            }
        });
    }
    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
    phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
}
```

Comment: Is `invokeAll()` not an option for you?

Comment: No, I don't want to queue tasks waiting to be invoked

Comment: I implemented this and this works. If anyone finds any loophole or a better way, please let me know. 

Answer (score 0):

I never used a  `Phaser` before but I think a `CountDownLatch` is the better way to handle this task.

A  `CountDownLatch` is a synchronization barier that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

2 methods are useful when using a `CountDownLatch` :

- `countDown` that decrements the counter when a task is finish.
- `await` is for the current thread (main for instance) to wait the others to complete.

*

```
private void executeTasks(TheadPoolExecutor threadPool, Iterator<String> it) {
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(threadPool.getPoolSize());

    for (final String id : IteratorUtils.iterable(it)) {
        threadPool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                thread.sleep(10000 * id.length());
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        });
    }
    countDownLatch.await();
  }
```

Here the CountDownLatch is initialized with  the number of threads in the threadpool.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I should have mentioned that my thread pool size is configurable and countdownlatch won't help me

Comment: It does not matter, because you pass a threadPool as a parameter. It only needs to get the number of threads in the poolsize

Comment: What if I want to increase the pool size? I cannot increment countdown latch right

Comment: The `CountDownLatch ` does not need to know about increasing the pool size. If you see in the method `executeTasks`, I pass the number of threads in the thread pool as a parameter for the latch.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I am saying that during the execution of my tasks I want to increase thread pool size. But since countdownlatch is created with initial thread pool size, it cannot be adjusted. Also, your implementation assumes that each thread just one task which is not the case.

Comment: Well you need to give more info of what you want to achieve

Comment: Well look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791851/can-you-dynamically-resize-a-java-util-concurrent-threadpoolexecutor-while-it-st

Comment: Sorry for not providing more details. I am able to adjust my threadpoolsize using setCorePoolSize() and setMaxPoolSize()

Comment: I provided more details in the question now